# SignatureDoesNotMatch error using restTemplate to get url request of S3

Tags: http, url, get, request, spring-resttemplate

I'm trying to send a HTTP GET request of S3 using restTemplate and I get SignatureDoesNotMatch error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Dose anyone know what can cause this error?

Comment: I had a problem like this once with presigned s3 urls. Once I went back to the docs, I discovered that I needed to use a specific param in two different places. I was using Boto3 and I needed to set the `acl` in both `Fields` and `Conditions`. Chances are good that reading the docs closely will help a lot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem!

Apparently that my question wasn't accurate, just like the error I got from S3 - not indicative.

What I was actually searching for is how to download a file from S3 url using Rest Template.
So I had to add the following configuration and used this code to solve it:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
String url = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), byte[].class);
```